# do you see any problem with that stored procedure template?

Tags: sql-server-2005, stored-procedures, error-handling, transactions, stack-trace

so I created that(I used some stuff found on other website) to handle transactions and having a sort of stacktrace while executing stored procedure that could call other stored procedure that need transaction and etc.

so if I have **A** calling **B** and **B** is calling **C** and **C** got an error, I can *correctly* rollback my stuff and returning a stacktrace saying: error in C follow the trace to find out where/how/etc...

do any of you find a problem with this logic?

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[NAME]
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON
    SET XACT_ABORT ON

    declare @trancount int
    set @trancount = @@trancount
    declare @savePointName varchar(40)
    set @savePointName = newid()

    BEGIN TRY  
        if @trancount = 0
            begin transaction
        else
            save transaction @savePointName

        /*
        //  STUFF HERE
        */

        if @trancount = 0
            commit transaction
    END TRY  
    BEGIN CATCH
        declare  @xstate int
        set @xstate = XACT_STATE()
        if @xstate = -1  and @trancount = 0
            rollback transaction
        if @xstate = 1 and @trancount = 0
            rollback transaction
        if @xstate = 1 and @trancount > 0
            rollback transaction @savePointName

        declare @message varchar(max)
            set @message = ERROR_MESSAGE() + 
                       ' (' + ERROR_PROCEDURE() + 
                       ':' + ltrim(str(ERROR_LINE())) + 
                       ', Raised ' + ltrim(str(ERROR_NUMBER())) +
                       ', Severity ' + ltrim(str(ERROR_SEVERITY())) +
                       ', State ' + ltrim(str(ERROR_STATE())) + ')'

        RAISERROR(@message,16,1)
    END CATCH
END
```

Comment: Is there an error you want us to look at ?

Comment: no, I want to know if anyone find any logic problem in it, so far it seem to work ok but it seem in adobe livecycle there might be a problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, I can't spot anything wrong with this code.